# AWS Lambda can't access mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'm deploying simple express CRUD API with serverless framework. It works fine until it comes to accessing databese, it returns {"message":"Internal Server Error"}. But when running locally it works as intended. Is there a problem with the way I'm connecting to mongoDB?

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { logger } = require("../Log/pino");
require("dotenv").config();

mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 5000});

const connection = mongoose.connection
  .once("open", () => {
    logger.info("connected to database");
  })
  .on("error", (err) => {
    logger.info(`mongoose error: ${err}`);
  });

module.exports = connection;
```

Comment: do you run this code in Lambda? is your lambda in a VPC?

Comment: How do you set `MONGO_URI` env var in Lambda? Lambda doesn't have the same `.env` file you might have locally

Comment: maybe better to do this? `MONGO_URI = process.env.MONGO_URI || 'MONGO_URI';`

Comment: Tried using MONGO_URI directly in this file as a string, but doesn't work. will check VPC now

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Problem was that I was only allowing access to mongoDB cluster to requests sent only from my IP. Changed cluster network access settings and it works now as it should.